# Facebook graph API how to hide { "id": "XXXX ", "post_id": "XXXX_XXXX " }

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I practice [this code](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) 
**Scenario 2: Creating a New Album and Adding a Photo**

After running,it will show

```
{
  "id": "XXXX ",
  "post_id": "XXXX_XXXX "
}
```

How can I　hide it and alert 'upload success' ? 
Please help me Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the response object send by the graph API. Find this line in your code and replace it with what you want to output: `$response = file_get_contents($token_url);`

Comment: I try~ but there is error  
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102
   }
}

Comment: Try `$response= "upload success"`